# WiFi, Ethernet, USB and HDMI not working after update Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo ideapad 510-15ikb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, peripherals

Yesterday night (16 feb 2023) my Ubuntu autoupdated some packages and after restart, most of my periperals are not working anymore. HDMI port, ethernet and wifi do not work at all, USB ports did not detect my phone/wifi dongle, but does detect a mouse.

After some searching I did find posts suggesting to try out an earlier kernel - this works, on the old kernel (old: 5.15.0-60-generic, new: 5.19.0-32-generic), everything works again.

My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad 510-15iKB

Other answers suggest updating packages and reloading network services, but those answers are a couple years old and often talking about upgrades from <20 to 20.04. Could someone provide me with some assistance on how to debug this issue? I will update the questions with output when people ask.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try installing and running kernel 6.1.12 - if it doesn't work, file a bug report here: bugzilla.kernel.org/

Comment: Thanks @ArtemS. I rely on this PC too often to install anything experimentally. As I understand kernel 5.15 is supported until oct '23 so I accepted below answer and will go with that solution for now

Comment: I too ran into this problem while setting up a fresh install and found I simply restarted at the wrong time, it still had to install 6.2.0-26 generic. Everything worked after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to boot the old working kernel. From the Grub screen, go to the Advanced options, then select the working kernel. If you need to make it the default, after booting the system, you have to remove the newest one (not recommended) or add the following lines to your  `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Finally run: `sudo update-grub`

Reboot once more and select the old kernel in GRUB. After that, booting should automatically select the old kernel.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Minor remark: after making the changes you mentioned and a reboot, I still ended up with kernel 19. Once more through the works in GRUB to select the 15 kernel, it then saved my choice and boots automatically into 15 now. I added this to your answer